# css: можно ли перемещать дочерние элементы внутри родительского чтобы размер родительского элемента автоматически изменялись

Tags: html, css, css3, position

подскажите, есть ли возможность не выставлять "вручную" точные размеры родительского блока перемещая внутри данного родительского блока дочерние (через `position: relative` или `transform: translate()`)?

привел пример - видно что перемещенный блок выходит за нижнюю границу родительского блока и не доходя до правой границы родительского блока

а хотелось бы чтобы элементы точно вписывались в родительский блок

я могу это сделать через ручное выставление координат и размера, но можно ли это сделать только через css автоматически?

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .group {
        display: inline-block;
        
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        font-size: 0;
        
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .group div {
        font-size:  20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .group div:not(.main) {
        width:  128px;
        height: 128px;
        
        border: 1px solid red;
        background: lime;
    }
    
    .main {
        transform: translate(-20px, 20px);
        
        width:  192px;
        height: 192px;
        
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class = 'group'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class = 'main'>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать margin

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .group {
        display: inline-flex;
        
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        font-size: 0;
        
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .group div {
        font-size:  20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .group div:not(.main) {
        width:  128px;
        height: 128px;
        
        border: 1px solid red;
        background: lime;
    }
    
    .main {
        margin: 20px 0 0 -20px;
        
        width:  192px;
        height: 192px;
        
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class = 'group'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class = 'main'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, мне честно говоря без разницы какой именно `display` будет, лишь бы достигался результат

Comment: @Sevastopol' Меня немного бомбануло, приношу извинения, ваш код конечно же интересен, но для такой задачи избыточен как по мне.

Answer (score 1):

> можно ли это сделать только через css автоматически?

Нельзя. Как минимум по двум причинам: 1я - используется `inline-block`, хотя, скорее это даже и не является причиной, но 2я самая главная - используется трансформация `transform: translate`, а это то же самое, что и абсолютное позиционирование. А значит родительский элемент "теряет" свой дочерний элемент, но при этом продолжает учитывать его ширину как бы, если бы он никуда не трансформировался.

Но, чтобы дать хоть какой-нибудь ответ, то предлагаю следующий вариант, конечно не автоматический, но а-ля полуавтоматический, то есть `выставлять "вручную" точные размеры` не двумя ручками, а только одной. :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --x: 128px;
  --y: 128px;
  --xM: 192px;
  --yM: 192px;
  --trX: -20px;
  --trY: 20px;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc((var(--x) * 2) + var(--xM) + var(--trX) + 2px);
  height: calc(var(--yM) + var(--trY) + 2px);
}

.group>div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.group>div:not(.main) {
  width: var(--x);
  height: var(--y);
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: lime;
}

.main {
  transform: translate(var(--trX), var(--trY));
  width: var(--xM);
  height: var(--yM);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='group'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class='main'>3</div>
</div>
```

Можно чуть проще через javascript

```js
const w = document.querySelector('.group').scrollWidth;
const h = document.querySelector('.main').scrollHeight;
document.querySelector('.group').style.setProperty('--w', w + 'px');
document.querySelector('.group').style.setProperty('--h', h + 'px');
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --trX: -20px;
  --trY: 20px;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(var(--w) + var(--trX) + 2px);
  height: calc(var(--h) + var(--trY) + 4px);
}

.group div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.group div:not(.main) {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: lime;
}

.main {
  transform: translate(var(--trX), var(--trY));
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='group'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class='main'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: что-то в данном коде блокам размеры не выставляются. Ну ок, с `transform/translate` ясно, но та же картина наблюдается и для `position: relative` - ее по тем же самым причинам не исправить?